# Convert FlowDocument to simple text

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

what is the most simple and elegant way how convert flowdocument to simple text?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about this?

```
string text = new TextRange(FlowDoc.ContentStart, FlowDoc.ContentEnd).Text;
```